# Error while publishing story on facebook using open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I want to post activity on user's facebook account.I have created one application on facebook which asks for publish_permissions and other necessary permissions.I am using like actions for this.The code I am using is:

```
 FacebookWebClient facebookWebClient = new FacebookWebClient(myAccessToken);

        string urlToPost= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes";
        string objects = "https://www.yahoo.com";

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
          { "object" ,  objects}
        };

        try
        {
            dynamic result = facebookWebClient.Post(urlToPost, parameters); 
            JObject friendListJson = JObject.Parse(result.ToString());
            string returval = friendListJson["id"].ToString();
            return returval;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
```

I am taking the accesstoken from database which I have previously stored when user gives permission to application. It is longterm accesstoken. I am using the same account to post activity in which I have created the application.Still I am facing the error **(OAuthException) (#3506) The action type likes:Like does not exist or is not approved, so app #AppID# can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app.  User #userID# is not one of those roles.**

I am stuck into this.Can anyone please tell me what am I missing to do?

Thanks,
Priya

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/#submitbuiltin

Comment: Right now I don't want to make it live. I just want to make it working for administrator.The same code is working with same application if I force user to login into facebook with my application, take fresh access token and use it. The problem is with the accesstoken I am using from database.But I am using the same access token for other functionalities too.Its not working for this task only.